# Is that good way to add a list to another list, fill default value if have no value from source list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two list string with capacity is: 20 and 10.

```
int maxCapacity = 20;
List<String> k = new ArrayList<>(maxCapacity);
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s.add(new String("X"));
}
s.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> k));
```

I want to add default value into K for index from 10 -> 19, Because the size of S is less then K, so it only enough to fill K from 0 -> 9.

I can do that by addition a loop, but seem it look not good:

```
for (int i = s.size(); i < maxCapacity; i++) {
    k.add("default");
}
```

Is that simple way to do? such as using stream java 8, etc.
Thank you.

Comment: So to clarify you want k to have {0, 1, 2... 9, "default", "default"...}?

Comment: The supplier passed to `toCollection` is expected to *create a new collection* on each evaluation. Returning an existing collection is broken, by definition. Besides that, don’t use `new String("X")`. Just use `"X"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do that could be :

```
k.addAll(s);
IntStream.range(s.size(), maxCapacity).forEach(i -> k.add(i, "default"));
```

Comment: By the way, those initializations are using `initialCapacity` and do not govern the size of the list. Hence hopefully you are ensuring the size of the list somewhere as posed in the question.